# Find all the monic polynomials P(x) ∈ C [X] satisfying the below condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

What are all the monic polynomials $P(X) \in \mathbb C [X]$, with simple roots such that $$P(X^n) = \pm P(X) P(\zeta X) P (\zeta^2 X) …P (\zeta^{n-1} X),$$ where ζ is a primitive n-th root of unity?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your questions lacks details and context. Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far? You can find some remarks about how to ask a good question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've recently stumbled upon this question asking to find all monic polynomials P ∈ R[X], with simple roots such that P(X^2)= ±P(X) P(-X). I've found those to be either x, x-1, or x(x-1). It seemed interesting to me that the coefficients of X from the RHS are 1 and -1, i.e. the 2-nd roots of unity. I was trying to find a generalisation for n, and actually my ideea is that the roots of P(x) are included into the roots of the equation x^n=x (however I'm not quite sure how I could prove it). Any help/suggestions are strongly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would guess that you would want to generalize to $$P(x^n)=\zeta^kP(x)P(\zeta x)\cdots P(\zeta^{n-1}x)$$ for some $k$.

Comment: That seems a bit more complicated than my initial approach, but I guess it could be an interesting requirement nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

This grew to long for a comment so I post it as an answer.

---

Let $P$ be any monic polynomial with only simple roots $r_1,\dots, r_n$. Then, $$P(X)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (X-r_i).$$ Now, $$P(X^n)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (X^n-r_i).$$ Thus, $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} P(\zeta^i X)=\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \prod\limits_{j=1}^n(\zeta^iX-r_j)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^n(X^n-r_i)=P(X^n).$$ The roots of $P(X^n)$ are the $n$-th roots of the $r_i$'s. So what you are asking for is an equality of products $$\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \prod\limits_{j=1}^n(\zeta^iX-r_j)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}(X-\zeta^j\sqrt[n]{r_i}).$$ Now compare the factors. On the RHS, the roots are the $n$-th roots of the roots of $P$. On the LHS the roots are $r_j\zeta^{-i}$. So in order to have equality, the roots need to coincide and you see that this is not necessarily true. In particular, you will want to allow now monic polynomials by polynomials with some root of unity as factor (to bring the LHS to a nicer form) and it also seems that $\sqrt[n]{r_i}=r_j$ should be a condition.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve followed a similar path myself and equaling the roots actually led me to believe that the roots of P satisfy the equation x^n=x. But I’m not sure I understand how allowing P to be a polynomial with some root of unity as a factor could bring the LHS to a nicer form, could you please explain?

Comment: To read of the roots, you want factors looking like $X-$something. One way to obtain this in our particular case is to write $\zeta^iX-r_i=\zeta^i(X-\zeta^{n-i}r_i)$. Now, doing so for every linear factor gives an additional $$\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\zeta^i$$ which should again be a root of unity. (In fact, checking with Wolfram:Alpha, it looks like it indeed is $\pm 1$.)

Comment: I must be doing/judging something wrong, but I can't manage to find the actual roots of P from this point on, I'll keep trying still and hopefully I'll find some clue to help me progress...